# How to ban users enter strings or negative numbers

Tags: c#

I tried to do a function this way, but once it shows the `MessageBox`, it then jumps out to the GUI and says the wrong message with the last sentence.

```
if (!(double.TryParse(Waisttb.Text, out waist) && double.TryParse(Heighttb.Text, out height))) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number!");
}
//no negative numbers
if (waist < 0 || height < 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number!");
} 
else {
    //change to doubles
    waist = double.Parse(Waisttb.Text);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more detail ?

Comment: Use a masked textbox!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reorder your logic. Also, there is no use in re-parsing the already parsed values.

```
if (!(double.TryParse(Waisttb.Text, out waist) && double.TryParse(Heighttb.Text, out height)))
{
    // input is not a valid number
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a vailable number!");
}
else if (waist < 0 || height < 0)
{
    // numbers are valid, but negative
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a vailable number!");
} 
else
{
    // numbers are valid and positive. use them here
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept an answer if it was useful to you. Also review previous posts you have done.